# SQL - which column is the maximum?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consider a simple table with integer values in col1,col2,col3

```
SELECT 
 "col1",
 "col2",
 "col3", 
 GREATEST("col1","col2","col3") AS "greatest_number" AS max_download 
FROM TEST_TBB_DEC_W_SPEEDS;
```

How can I return the field which tells me *which column* is the greatest one - instead of just the greatest value?

(I'm using the SQL version that comes w/ Snowflake, hence the use of `GREATEST`, but I'd be curious to see other answers that don't use this common extension too)

Comment: How would you like to handle ties?  For example, if Col1 AND Col2 each have the same (and highest) value?

Comment: Good point - I'd like to list them both I guess

Comment: But if that's fiddly then any one would do

Comment: I noticed that your previous question is also around the challenges of working with many columns.  This could in itself constitute an argument for normalising your format; wide "flat-file" tables do have their uses, but SQL as a language is very much designed around normalised structures (fewer columns, more rows).

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake `GREATEST`/`LEAST` functions could work with ARRAY type. The first value is the column value, the second is the column name.

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 3 AS col1, 2 AS col2, 1 AS col3 UNION ALL 
SELECT 323,       45,        5655      UNION ALL 
SELECT 20,        30,        10;
```

Query:

```
SELECT GREATEST(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(col1, 'col1'),
                ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(col2, 'col2'), 
                ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(col3, 'col3')) AS g
     ,g[0]::number  AS val
     ,g[1]::varchar AS column_name
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case greatest(col1, col2, col3)
            when col1 then 'col1' when col2 then 'col2' when col3 then 'col3'
        end)
```

Comment: what if there are 100 columns?

and is there a way to do it without using GREATEST?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull . . . I can't think of a simple method.  You should probably be storing these values in separate rows or perhaps an array.

Comment: Cool no worries - I'm newish to SQL, and by @MatBailie 's comment I should be considering normalizing the data structures in this way

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything to test snowflake code on, but you could 'unpivot' the data (one row per value, instead of one column per value), then pick the top ranking row.

*(Assumes that each source row has a unique `id` column.)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY col_value DESC)  AS ranking
  FROM
    TEST_TBB_DEC_W_SPEEDS
  UNPIVOT
  (
    col_value FOR col_name IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., coln)
  )
)
  AS ranked
WHERE
  ranking = 1
```